# Instalar login y register en la nueva version de laravel 9

Tags: laravel, laravel-9, vite

Tengo problemas al momento de instalar el login y register con auth de bootstrap.
intento instalar una version anterior de laravel asi:

composer create-project laravel/laravel proyecto "9.0.1"

Pero me termina por instalar la version "Laravel v9.23.0".
ok, asi que sigo con la instalacion de laravel /ui ejecutando los siguientes comandos.

composer require laravel/ui

php artisan ui bootstrap --auth

npm install

npm run dev

cuando ejecuto esto, todo ok.
cuando ingreso a la pagina carga bien, y el link de register y login aparecen.
pero cuando le doy click a login o register me sale un error:

> Vite manifest not found at:
> C:\xampp\htdocs\proyecto\public/build/manifest.json

este es mi archivo packaje.json

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "mix",
        "watch": "mix watch",
        "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
        "hot": "mix watch --hot",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "mix --production"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@popperjs/core": "^2.10.2",
        "axios": "^0.25",
        "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.6",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "postcss": "^8.1.14",
        "sass": "^1.32.11"
    }
}
```

que podria hacer?
gracias.
Es un proyecto totalmente nuevo.
y no habia tenia inconvenientes, solo hasta ahora con la nueva version,que trae vite y no se que es eso.

Comment: A partir de la versión 9 de Laravel, este último trabaja con `Vite`  y anteriormente trabajaba con `Webpack`, intenta agregando en tu `package.json` esto `"scripts": {  "dev": "vite", "build": "vite build" },`  y luego ejecuta npm run dev` también puedes buscar en youtube como cambiar `vite` por Webpack` en `Laravel 9`

Comment: Debes eliminar los del webpack, deja solo `"private": true, "scripts": { "dev": "vite",  "build": "vite build" },`

Answer (score 0):

haciendo pruebas instalé la ultima version.

> laravel new project

despues de esto, repetí los pasos para -auth

> composer require laravel/ui
>
> php artisan ui bootstrap --auth
>
> npm install
>
> npm run dev

y segui teniendo el mismo problema,
pero resulta que cuando ejecuto,

> npm run dev

en la versiones anteriores este me salia un mensaje de MIX ejecutado exitosamente, ahora con vite me sale un mensaje parecido a cuando ejecuto

> PHP ARTISAN SERVE

normalmente no ejecuto este comando para visualizar mis proyectos, simplemente lo guardo en una carpeta de xampp, y a travez de xampp veo mis proyectos.
Cuando hago esto, e intento dar click en login o register sale el mismo error.
pero si antes de darle click, ejecuto el npm run dev, y mientras se esta ejecutando voy y le doy click a login o register, ahora si funciona.
es decir, ahora funciona, pero desde mi punto de vista, funciona parcialmente.
habra alguna manera de solucionar esto?
que no tenga que estar ejecutando npm run dev, siempre que desee usar mi proyecto?

NOTA: si ejecuto

> php artisan serve

y voy al proyecto... no me funciona el login o register, regreso al punto anterior.

mi actual package.json

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vite build"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@popperjs/core": "^2.10.2",
        "axios": "^0.27",
        "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
        "laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.5.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "postcss": "^8.1.14",
        "sass": "^1.32.11",
        "vite": "^3.0.0"
    }
}
```

me sigue mostrando el error

Vite manifest not found at:
C:\xampp\htdocs\proyecto\public/build/manifest.json

Para que finalmente funcionara, ademas de darte npm install, npm run dev.
para que todo quedara funcional.
debi correr

> npm run build

y ya todo funcionó.

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso funciona bien seguir estos pasos:

```
composer require laravel/ui
```

y luego

```
php artisan ui:auth
```

nada más.